# Flow: Dynamically generate string union types?

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

Let's say I have a flow type `Suit`, and I want to compose it into another type called `Card`.

```
// types.js

type Suit =
  | "Diamonds"
  | "Clubs"
  | "Hearts"
  | "Spades";


type Card = {
  ...
  suit: Suit,
  ...
}
```

Rather than hard-coding in the Suit strings directly in suit.js, is it possible to dynamically generate the `Suit` type based on a JavaScript primitive (array)? Say...

```
// constants.js

const SUITS = ['Diamonds', 'Clubs', 'Hearts', 'Spades'];
```

This way the suits can be defined just once, and inside a JavaScript construct that will for re-use in other sections of the app. For example, a component elsewhere in the app that needs access to all the available suits:

```
// component.js

SUITS.map((suit: Suit): void => { ... });
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I don't think that Flow currently has this functionality. I usually end up writing string literals twice (once as a type, once as a value) if I need to do what you've described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in fact possible using the utility type [$Keys](https://flowtype.org/docs/utility-types.html#keyst):

```
const SUITS = {
    Diamonds: 'Diamonds',
    Clubs: 'Clubs',
    Hearts: 'Hearts',
    Spades: 'Spades',
};

type Suit = $Keys<typeof SUITS>

const suit1 : Suit = 'Diamonds'; // OK
const suit2 : Suit = 'Foo'; // Type error
```

Note that for this example, the values in SUITS don't actually matter, flow will look at the keys in `SUITS`. `type Suit` will be like the union type `type Suit = 'Diamonds' | 'Clubs' | ...`

Comment: Is it possible to do this if SUITS is defined as an array? (Since the values don't have any effect if SUITS is an object anyway)

Comment: I tried that, but that doesn't seem to be supported. It didn't error but I couldn't figure out how to make it work. But that's a small price to pay :)